VB6 Add-Ins only show when Running as Administrator (Windows 11)
I recently installed a version of VB6 (Enterprise) on a Windows 11 machine. When I previously ran VB6 on Windows 10, I was able to utilize the popular mouse-wheel fix add-in by calling regsvr32 <addin_path>.dll (running as admin) and then VB6 would be able to recognize the add-in and show it in the add-in manager. However, when I run VB6 with non-elevated rights, none of these add-ins (including the ones that supposedly come with the installation) appear in the manager.

Due to policy, I can't have the user simply run VB6 as an admin every time they want to use it.
Here's what I've done so far:

I have located the registry key created by making the regsvr32 call (HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\VB6IDEMouseWheel.Connect) and then have duplicated this in the same location, just under HKCU, instead.
I tried placing and registering the .dll in the same folder that the VB6 executable lies (of course unregistering any previous attempts before re-registering).
I edited the security settings of the folder where the executable (and .dll) for users and programs to have the same access as admin levels.

I'm not sure if this would have any effect on this issue, but during the install, I unchecked the ActiveX and the ADO, RDS, and OLE DB Providers components. I found that if I didn't do this, the install wouldn't work on windows 11. I also ran the install in compatibility mode for Windows XP Service Pack 3.



There is no solution to your problem. Visual Basic 6 is unsupported by Microsoft in 2024. I am even shocked you got it working on Windows 11. You can try compatibility mode but I seriously doubt that will change the fact the program requires elevated permissions. Running the installer in compatibility mode does NOT result in the application running in compatibility mode.

You will probably have to enable ADO if you want ActiveX add-ons to work. Moving DLLs into the executable directory probably isn’t going to achieve your goals.

@Ramhound I'm unsure why but unchecking the ActiveX controls and the ADO were the only way I could get it to install. If that's the case, then yeah, this might be dead in the water. I'll wait to see if anybody else has some wizardry hanging around.

You say "due to policy". What policy? Is this an enterprise computer managed by a domain or other computer management framework? Please clarify this.

@music2myear Yes, this is for a domain-managed enterprise computer. Users must submit a ticket anytime they need admin rights to do something, which takes a while and will waste a lot of time for devs if they have to do this every time they need to open the IDE. Without IT supplying credntials, they can't do anything elevated.

@Javery - You do realize your running 20 year old software that by all accounts probably has several security vulnerabilities against it? If your company requires Visual Basic 6, then they need to adjust the policies enough, so it can work. Most IDEs are not 20 years old, the vast majority work perfectly, with elevated permissions

*without elevated permissions. Most applications do NOT require an Administrator to run it.

The solution is actually described in a really old Microsoft TechNet KnowledgeBase article (Q190212), which is no longer available:
Q190212: BUG: Add-Ins Only Visible to the User Who Installs VB
In summary:

Export the following registry keys for a user where the addins are showing correctly (i.e. the Administrator user):
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Visual Basic\6.0\Addins
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Visual Basic\6.0\AddInToolbar

Import these .reg files, when logged in as the target user.


Step #2 (importing the .reg file) will need to be done for each user on the machine.  Alternatively, you could use something like Active Setup to apply this to each user on their next login.
Source: https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/190/Q190212/

So you were only able to get this to work for some users, or no users? Maybe rephrase the "I was not able..." bit to say "I was only able to make this work for some users, not all..." to clarify that point?

I have fixed the advice around "all users" now.
